# Combining Stack and Bar Chart in Primefaces

Tags: primefaces

---

Hi everybody,

I m new at JSF and Primefaces. I use Primefaces 3.5 , Spring and Apache Tomcat 7 server. My question is , I have three series for my Cartesian Chart and they have same key. Like serie1(key, value) , serie2(key, value) and serie3(key, value). So i want to draw my first two series stacked and my third serie is a bar next to others. Can i do it with Primefaces? If i can, how?

My HTML code:

```
      <p:outputPanel id="myPanel">
      <p:barChart id="basic" value="#{myBean.categoryModel}" legendPosition="ne"  
        title="Title"  style="height:450px" animate="true" yaxisLabel="Yaxis" xaxisLabel="Xaxis" datatipFormat="#{myBean.dataTipFormat}"/> 

       </p:outputPanel>
```

My JSF Code:

```
firstYear.set(myMap.get(export.getGensek()), export1.value().divide(new      BigDecimal(1000000)));
secondYear.set(myMap.get(export.getGensek()), export2.value().divide(new BigDecimal(1000000)));
aprroxYear.set(myMap.get(export.getGensek()), export3.value().divide(new BigDecimal(1000000)));
categoryModel.addSeries(approxYear);
categoryModel.addSeries(firstYear);  
categoryModel.addSeries(secondYear);
```

So i want to show aprroxyear and firstyear at stacked and show secondyear just like bar next to others.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can. Show us what you've tried so that we can offer you some help.

Comment: Sorry. First question. I added my codes. Thanks.